# Convert string to date with format in java

Tags: java, types, date-conversion

I want to convert String to Date using following format: "yyyy-MM-dd"

```
public class TestProgram {

public static void main(String[] args) {

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -2);
        Date toDelete = new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis());
        SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String formatDate = s.format(toDelete);
        System.out.println( "Date before 2 Days: " + formatDate);
}
```

}

Current datatype format is String, I want to convert this in Date datatype, how to do that with this format [yyyy-MM-dd].?

Comment: s.parse(formatDate);

Comment: Current format is in String type, I want in Date data type, how to do that?

Comment: A `Date` doesn't have a format.

Comment: @javadeveloper I answered this question in my previous comment

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could do something like this just to get Date format:

`String yourdate = "2015-04-08";
Date date = java.sql.Date.valueOf(yourdate);`

Alternatively I recommend using Apache/Joda libraries for date manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is:

```
    //formatDate is String containing date
    SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date parsedDate = s.parse(formatDate);
```

Comment: Note this will not be exactly the same time you used in your code because it will be rounded to days.

Comment: I tried this, but this is not giving "yyyy-mm-dd" this format, instead its giving "Mon Apr 06 00:00:00 PDT 2015"

Comment: Well s.parse gets you Date from string s.format gives you String from date to provided format.